# How to prevent scrolling page up/ down when closing jQuery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a `Shiny` application and I'm using `dialog` (`jQuery`) for it.

The problem is that, when I close the `dialog`, the page goes to the top and I would like it to stay in the same position when I close the `dialog`.

The problem is that, when I close the `dialog`, the page goes up or down (as if it adjusted the screen position). I didn't want that to happen. I want the page to stay in the same position when I close the `dialog`.

When I open the `dialog` there are no problems, only when I close it.

My code:

```
<head>

  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js'></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {

      $('#text1').hide();

      $('#text1').dialog({
          autoOpen: false
        }, {
          modal: true
        }, {
          title: 'Bird'
        }, {
          width: 50
        }, {
          resizable: false
        }, {
          show: 'explode',
          hide: 'explode'
        }, {
          closeText: null
        },

        ///background-color header
        {
          open: function() {
            $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
          }
        }
      ).prev('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css({
        'background-color': '#f8d40c',
        'color': '#333333',
        'text-align': 'center',
        'display': 'block',
        'margin': 'auto',
        'border-radius': '5px',
        'font-size': '25px'
      });

      ///background-color body
      $('#text1').css('background-color', '#e3d47f');

      $('#click1').on('click', function() {
        $('#text1').dialog('option', 'position', {
          at: 'left top',
          of: this // this refers to the cliked element
        }).dialog('open');
        return false;

      });

      $('body').on('click', '.ui-widget-overlay', function() {

        $('#text1').dialog('close');

      });

    });

  </script>

  <style>
    .class1 {
      margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <p class='class1'>Point</p>

  <p class='class1'>Point</p>

  <p id="text1">Open dialog</p>
  
  <p id="click1" class='class1' style='color:red'>Click here</p>

</body>
```

- `Shiny App` is a SPA (Single Page Application).

Comment: just save the scrolltop value and restore it  when the dialog is closed

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't know much about `JS`. Could you provide an answer? Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop